# Unable to store Japanese characters in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mariadb

We are trying to store some text with Japanese characters inside Maria DB 5. However, we can see only question marks after save.

We tried to set UTF-8 encoding with following command, but this also does not help.

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db COLLATE = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA where schema_name = 'my_db';
```

Any clues?

Comment: Likely your ***connection encoding*** when you try to insert the data is not set to `utf8`/`utf8mb4`. The details on how to remedy that will depend on the details how you connect to the database.

Comment: I tried to save using MySQLWorkbench as well as from my application. Can you direct me to correct way of connecting? I may get some clue then.

Comment: I don't know MySQLWorkbench, but for PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/476

Comment: Show us the symptoms.  Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored will give you further info.